# How to add "addtowishlist" and "addtocart" in a custom phtml?

Tags: product, addtocart, wishlist

I have a custom loop for my website and I need to add **addtowishlist** and **addtocart** buttons in my foreach. How to add this buttons in Magento? I marked in the end of code where I need to insert the buttons.

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                        ->getCollection()
                        // add sorting to collection optional
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('a_pecas_assinadas', array('eq' => 1))
                        ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC')
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->load();

foreach ($_productCollection as $_product){
    $t++;
    if($t==1){$variavel='first';}
    elseif($t==5){$variavel='last';}
    else{$variavel='';}

    if($t <= 5){
        echo '<div class="col-md-15 txtleft">';
            echo '<div class="'.$variavel.' produtos">';
                echo '<a class="ocinza upper" href="'.$_product->getProductUrl().'">';
                    echo '<img src="'.$url.$_product->getImage().'">';
                echo '</a>';
                echo '<span class="hidden">'.$_product->getId().'</span>';
                echo '<p class="fs14 fw700" style="margin:10px auto 5px">';
                    echo '<a class="ocinza upper" href="'.$_product->getProductUrl().'">';
                        echo $_product->getName();
                    echo '</a>';
                echo '</p>';
                echo '<div class="row opensans fs16">';
                    echo '<div class="col-md-12"><span class="lnt">'.money_format('%n', $_product->getPrice()).'</span>';
                    echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="verde">'.money_format('%n', $_product->getSpecialPrice()).'</span></div>';
                echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';

        -------> echo '<a>addtowishlist</a>';
        -------> echo '<a>addtocart</a>';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These codes should give you add to cart and wishlist buttons.

For add to cart:

```
<a href="<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="button btn btn-cart">Add to Cart</a>
```

For wishlist:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product); ?>" class="button btn btn-wishlist">Add to Wishlist</a>
```

Hope this helps.